# Inserting date with month name in datetime field column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert  a date & time value into table

Here is my query

```
Insert INTO tableName(attDate) VALUES ("22-Sep-2019 19:28:10")
```

Here attDate column is having type datetime,  i have tried above query using DATE_FORMAT function but no luck. And also i am not suppose to use the date value in a variable. Will anybody guide me to proper way.

Comment: if the datatype is `DATETIME` it needs to be in the format  `'2019-09-22 19:28:10'`

Comment: Yeah thats true, but i having input in form of "22-Sep-2019 19:28:10" and anyhow have to work with it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Guess I misunderstood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert a datetime value to MySQL datetime format (**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**)

```
Insert INTO tableName(attDate) 
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('22-Sep-2019 19:28:10', '%d-%b-%Y %T'))
```

Details:

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%b`     Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- `%T`     Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Thanks Madhur Ji, really explained it will, your answer really helped to fix my problem, thanks for solving my headache,  Accepted the answer